# After Videoview starting, setText commend not working properly

Tags: android, android-videoview

well i am planning a interface such as a video play background and some text appear on it. I am using videoview and normal textiev and normal buttons. like a spotify app's intro.

so I create 2 methods
for video opening

```
 public void video_ac(String x){
    adres = null;
    adres = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
            + "/"
            + "raw/" +x);

    videoView.setVideoURI(adres);
    videoView.start();
}
```

for set text

```
public void yazdir (String a, String b, String c)
{
    ly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    icerik_yazisi.setText("");
    icerik_yazisi.setCharacterDelay(150);
    icerik_yazisi.animateText(a);
    BT_olumlu.setText(b);
    BT_olumsuz.setText(c);
}
```

this codes working perfect in on create method but it is not working after button click listener.

```
      BT_olumlu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sorgula2(BT_olumlu.getText().toString());
            ly.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    })
```

and my methods:

```
public void sorgula2 (String sss){
    if (sss.equals("oyuna başla")){

        video_ac("abc");
        yazdir("yoldan geçen kamyonetn rengi hangisidir ..", "mavi tır " ,"sarı kamyonet");

    }

    else if(sss.equals("sarı kamyonet")){

        video_ac("bca");
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                yazdir(".. olay nerede gerçekleşmiş.", "otopark" ,"havalimanı");
            }

        });

    }
```

the problem is showing video goes in infinite loops and not stoping and settext methods never work in first condition, I can only show text in videoview complete method. ( second conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED, may be in the future, useful for someone, the problem is onclick listener. I ve changed it and solved.

```
BT_olumlu.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // PRESSED
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // RELEASED

                    icerik_yazisi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    sorgula2(BT_olumlu.getText().toString());
                    return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```